# Adding QT5 libraries to CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm new to using CMake. I'm trying to create a simple CMakeList file and add support for QPrinter and QTextDocument from QT5 5.7. From what  I've found ill have to add the following libraries to my CMakeList file:

- QT5Core
- QT5PrintSupport
- Qt5Gui
- Qt5Widgets

This is what i have right now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR) 
PROJECT (photobooth)

find_package( Qt5Core )
find_package( Qt5PrintSupport )
find_package( Qt5Gui )
find_package( Qt5Widgets )

set( NAME_SRC
    src/main.cpp
    src/photobooth.cpp      
)

set( NAME_HEADERS 
    include/photobooth.h          

)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
link_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

add_executable( photobooth ${NAME_SRC} ${NAME_HEADERS} )

target_link_libraries( photobooth Qt5::Widgets )
target_link_libraries( photobooth Qt5::Core )
target_link_libraries( photobooth Qt5::Qt5PrintSupport )
target_link_libraries( photobooth Qt5::Qt5Gui )
```

This is the output from Cmake:

```
Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5PrintSupport" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5Gui" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5PrintSupport" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5Gui" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5PrintSupport" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5Gui" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5PrintSupport" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5Gui" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0020 is not set: Automatically link Qt executables to qtmain
  target on Windows.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0020" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5PrintSupport" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "photobooth" links to target "Qt5::Qt5Gui" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Generating done
```

My project generates fine with Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 as my build. Also when i include QTextDocument in main.cpp it finds it but not QPrinter. Is there anything I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: maybe you forget to add include directory of qmake for exemple `target_include_directories(photobooth ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. Have you read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) ? by the way try to upgrade your cmake version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some tips:

```
find_package( Qt5Core )
find_package( Qt5PrintSupport )
find_package( Qt5Gui )
find_package( Qt5Widgets )
```

You can merge these calls in one `find_package` looking for Qt5:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED
    Core
    PrintSupport
    Gui
    Widgets
)
```

Note the use of the keyword `REQUIRED` which will cause CMake to raise an error if the package can't be found. Looking in your error log, that may be your issue. Did you set `Qt5_DIR` somewhere?

`Core` and `Gui` are optional here since `Widgets` depends on them, so they will be added automatically.

You should change your required version for CMake to `2.8.11` to ensure imported targets embed include directories.

You should consider `target_include_directories` instead of `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` to avoid global pollution, and attach the parameter to the target. This is not a real point here, but a good practice for future bigger projects.

Your call to `link_directories` is useless here. If you need to link against libraries, prefer `target_link_libraries` anyway.

[`EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH.html) is an old variable, superceded by `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` which is a target property.

Once cleaned, your CMake project may looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT (photobooth)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED
    Widgets
    PrintSupport
)

set( NAME_SRC
    src/main.cpp
    src/photobooth.cpp
)
set( NAME_HEADERS
    include/photobooth.h
)

add_executable( photobooth ${NAME_SRC} ${NAME_HEADERS} )

set_target_properties(photobooth PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
)

target_include_directories(photobooth PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries( photobooth Qt5::Widgets Qt5::PrintSupport )
```

Answer (score 2):

You require "2.8" version of CMake, which is **too low** for use features of Qt like imported targets and automatical linking to qtmain on Windows. This is exactly what policy warnings are about.

Instead use

```
cmake_minimium_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
```

(*FATAL_ERROR* option is no longer needed for this version).

Note, that even you have CMake 2.8.12, it emulates *exact* version which you write in `cmake_minimium_required` command.