# build Qt5 project with cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, point-cloud-library

I am trying to build a Qt5 project with cmake, here is my cmake code(VS2013 as generator):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project      (pcl-visualizer)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt2013\\5.7\\msvc2013_64")
set(VTK_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\PCL 1.8.0\\3rdParty\\VTK\\lib\\cmake\\vtk-7.0")
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package (VTK REQUIRED)
find_package (PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)

include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories    (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions     (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})

set  (project_SOURCES main.cpp pclviewer.cpp)
set  (project_HEADERS pclviewer.h)
set  (project_FORMS   pclviewer.ui)
set  (VTK_LIBRARIES   vtkRendering vtkGraphics vtkHybrid QVTK)

ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE  (pcl_visualizer ${project_SOURCES}
                                ${project_FORMS_HEADERS}
                                ${project_HEADERS_MOC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (pcl_visualizer ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

And it configured and generated.

> -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: C:/ysong/pcl/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer/build
>   10:40:24: Le processus "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" s'est
>   terminé normalement. 10:40:24: Impossible de trouver un Makefile.
>   Vérifiez vos options de compilation.  Erreur lors de la
>   compilation/déploiement du projet pcl_visualizer (kit : Desktop Qt
>   5.6.1 MSVC2013 64bit2) When executing step "Make" 10:40:24: Temps écoulé : 00:01.

But the project is not built(no ui_pclviewer.h). What should I do to build completely my project.

Comment: CMake doesn't built projects. CMake simply prepares the building environment. Open the .sln project (i assume you are on windows) and build from visual studio

Comment: Yes,I have a sln project. But to build a qt project, qt has to compile the "*.ui" file to a "ui_*.h" file to be used in visual studio. I have to do this manually?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#manual:cmake-qt(7) You want AUTOMOC and AUTOUIC probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40397293/6612932), your CMake file first need to be cleaned.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
```

`2.6` is too old and I'm pretty sure you don't really need to be that far compatible with old versions. Use `2.8.11` at the very least.

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt2013\\5.7\\msvc2013_64")
```

Avoid "\" in your paths, sooner or later you will have trouble with that. Use "/" instead, even on Windows:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt2013/5.7/msvc2013_64")
```

You may also set `Qt5_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, like you did for vtk.

Don't find each Qt module one by one with:

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Core)
```

Add them all with one call:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Widgets)
```

`Widgets` is enough since Qt's package files handle dependencies. Add `REQUIRED` to ensure packages are found.

Using [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets), `AUTOMOC` and `AUTOUIC`, your cmake project should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(pcl-visualizer)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(Qt5_DIR "C:/Qt2013/5.7/msvc2013_64/lib/cmake/Qt5")
set(VTK_DIR "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.0/3rdParty/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.0")
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Widgets)
find_package (VTK REQUIRED)
find_package (PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)

include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories    (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions     (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set  (project_SOURCES main.cpp pclviewer.cpp)
set  (project_HEADERS pclviewer.h)
set  (project_FORMS   pclviewer.ui)
set  (VTK_LIBRARIES   vtkRendering vtkGraphics vtkHybrid QVTK)

add_executable(pcl_visualizer ${project_SOURCES}
                              ${project_FORMS}
                              ${project_HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(pcl_visualizer Qt5::Widgets ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: `@wasthishelpful`, how are the variables `${project_FORMS_HEADERS}` and `${project_HEADERS_MOC}` defined? Are they automatically generated from `${project_FORMS}` and `${project_HEADERS}`? Or is this a typo? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: To make the CMakeLists portable, the variables should be set as environment variables in the system instead. This way other users can compile the software without having to edit the project's CmakeLists.txt