# Qt5 Debian 8 (Jessie) CMake error with Qt5::X11Extras

Tags: cmake, debian, qt5

I am struggling with the following issue and I really wish someone could provide me with helpful tips.

When building my C++ application based on Qt5.8 using CMake 3.8.2, I got the following error during the "generate" step:

```
    CMake Error at ntActions/ntActionsITK/CMakeLists.txt:81 (ADD_LIBRARY):
    Target "ntActionsITK" links to target "Qt5::X11Extras" but the target 
    was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
    target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

These are the two lines of my CMakeLists, where the issue is arising:

```
    80 - ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_GUI_LIBS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT3_SUPPORT)
    81 - ADD_LIBRARY(ntActions ${ntActionsGUI_SRCS} ${ntActions_GUI}
```

My PATH variable includes QT5.8 install path (lib, lib/CMake, bin, include). 
CMake is able to automatically find all Qt5 packages I am using, including Qt5X11Extras.

Am I missing something?

My dev env. is the following: Debian 8, Qt(5.8), CMake(3.8.2)

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks 
Bouba

ADD: qt5Setup.cmake file

Hi Tsyvarev, thanks for your feedback. I have a qt5Setup.cmake file to setup Qt5, as follows:

```
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui Network Concurrent OpenGL 
    Svg PrintSupport Sql SerialPort MultimediaWidgets X11Extras)

    IF(QT_USE_FILE)
      INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
    ENDIF(QT_USE_FILE)

    include_directories(
    ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Network_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Svg_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Concurrent_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5PrintSupport_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Sql_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${QtSerialPort_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5MultimediaWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5X11Extras_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${Qt5Svg_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Network_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Widget_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Sql_LIBRARIES}
    ${QtSerialPort_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5MultimediaWidgets_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5PrintSupport_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5X11Extras_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: With this type of CMake error message referenced line has a little meaning: Problem is not how do you *create* the library, but how do you **link** it. Provide other parts of your code, which includes: `find_package(Qt5)` call, `target_link_libraries(ntActions)` or `qt5_use_modules(ntActions)`. Have you some warnings during the configuration, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392487/adding-qt5-libraries-to-cmake)? BTW, it seems strange for me that call `add_library(ntActions)` creates "ntActions**ITK**" target.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, thanks for your feedback. I have a qt5Setup.cmake file to setup Qt5, as follows:

Comment: Can you check that target `Qt5::X11Extras` **actually exists** after `find_package(Qt5)`? E.g., with addition of these lines after `find_package()`: `if(TARGET Qt5::X11Extras)`, `message("Target Qt5::X11Extras exists")`, `endif()`. Which `CMakeLists.txt` `include()`s script `qt5Setup.cmake`?

Comment: Yep, the target exists. CMake detects it as expected. The CMake detailed above is used by NTLibMacros.cmake script via the following lines: (MACRO(NTLib_USE_QT5)
INCLUDE(${NTLib_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/qt5Setup.cmake)  
ENDMACRO(NTLib_USE_QT5)

Comment: In ntActions folder, there are additional subdirectories, among them ntActionsITK, which creates ntActionsITK target. ntAction builds an application on top of that.

Comment: @BoubakeurBelaroussi did you find any solutions to  your problem? I have the same issue.